# Multiple LESS files with grunt

Tags: gruntjs, less

I can't figure out how to get multiples less files with grunt :

```
less: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/main.css': ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/main.less']
        },
        options: {
          sourceMap: true,
          sourceMapFilename: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/main.css.map',
          sourceMapBasepath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/',
          sourceMapRootpath: '/'
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the expanded file syntax of grunt (http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically). For exampe, to compile all lib/less/*.less to build/css/*.css:

```
less: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'lib/less',
      src: ['*.less'],
      dest: 'build/css',
      ext: '.css'
    }]
  }
},
```